# Prolog parsing is running out of stack

Tags: parsing, prolog, dcg, failure-slice, non-termination

I have this code

```
s(W) :- append(W1,W2,W), np(W1), vp(W2).

vp(W) :- append(W1,W2,W), v(W1), np(W2).

np(W) :-
   (  append(W1,W2,W), pn(W1), ph(W2)
   ;  append(W1,W2,W), det(W1), n(W2)
   ).

pn([hans]).

ph([]).

v([beobachtet]).

n([mann]).
n([fernrohr]).

p([mit]).

det([den]).
det([dem]).
```

when I cast something like `np(X).` `vp(X).` or `pp(X)` get one possible parse and then an out of stack error. when I cast `s(X).` I don't even get a parse. I know that is because there is some infinite loop running, but I just cant point out at which point it gets looped. i figured it might happen because of using the same names for all my variables, but then I changed them to individual ones and it didn't change anything.

any one got a hint?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Reason for out of stack

Let's look at the following line from your code:

```
vp(W) :- append(W1,W2,W), v(W1), np(W2).
```

Running `append(W1, W2, W)` in isolation gives the following:

```
?- append(W1, W2, W).
W1 = [],
W2 = W ;
W1 = [_G1108],
W = [_G1108|W2] ;
W1 = [_G1108, _G1114],
W = [_G1108, _G1114|W2] ;
W1 = [_G1108, _G1114, _G1120],
W = [_G1108, _G1114, _G1120|W2] .
```

As you can see, `W1` is a list of increasing length. Only for length 1 does it give a solution (since `v(W1)`). After this first instantiation, `W1` gets longer and longer and longer and ..., but `v(W1)` will not succeed for lists of longer length.

#### DCG grammar

In Prolog you can use DCG notation to create a grammar. Your grammar would look as follows:

```
s --> np, vp.
np --> pn.
np --> det, n.
vp --> v, np.

det --> [den].
det --> [dem].

n --> [mann].
n --> [fernrohr].

pn --> [hans].

v --> [beobachtet].
```

#### Example of use

```
?- phrase(s, S).
S = [hans, beobachtet, hans] ;
S = [hans, beobachtet, den, mann] ;
S = [hans, beobachtet, den, fernrohr] ;
S = [hans, beobachtet, dem, mann] ;
S = [hans, beobachtet, dem, fernrohr] ;
S = [den, mann, beobachtet, hans] ;
S = [den, mann, beobachtet, den, mann] ;
S = [den, mann, beobachtet, den, fernrohr] ;
S = [den, mann, beobachtet, dem, mann] ;
S = [den, mann, beobachtet, dem, fernrohr] ;
S = [den, fernrohr, beobachtet, hans] ;
S = [den, fernrohr, beobachtet, den, mann] ;
S = [den, fernrohr, beobachtet, den, fernrohr] ;
S = [den, fernrohr, beobachtet, dem, mann] ;
S = [den, fernrohr, beobachtet, dem, fernrohr] ;
S = [dem, mann, beobachtet, hans] ;
S = [dem, mann, beobachtet, den, mann] ;
S = [dem, mann, beobachtet, den, fernrohr] ;
S = [dem, mann, beobachtet, dem, mann] ;
S = [dem, mann, beobachtet, dem, fernrohr] ;
S = [dem, fernrohr, beobachtet, hans] ;
S = [dem, fernrohr, beobachtet, den, mann] ;
S = [dem, fernrohr, beobachtet, den, fernrohr] ;
S = [dem, fernrohr, beobachtet, dem, mann] ;
S = [dem, fernrohr, beobachtet, dem, fernrohr].
```

Comment: `den, fernrohr`  that hurts! Akk. neutr. is `das` - but definitely should mean `mit, dem, fernrohr`

Comment: @false Indeed, I've just copy-pasted the grammar from the question (leaving out undefined predicates such as `ph/1`). The questioner should add prepositional phrases (`np --> np, pp. pp --> pre, np`) and features for singular/plural matching between `np` and `vp` and the like, making the solutions more *ähnlich* to German :-)

Comment: Thanks for helping me with this simplified code. But isn't there any way to do this with append? I mean why exactly is W1 increasing infinitly?

Comment: @bngschmnd I address this at the beginning of my answer. Also see the answer given by false, which explains how you can debug such cases in general by a technique called 'failure slicing'.

Answer (score 4):

Non-termination is often a bit difficult to understand in Prolog. Take as example the query `pn(X)`. Obviously, there should be:

```
?- pn(X).
   W = [hans]
;  W = [den,mann]
;  W = [den,fernrohr]
;  W = [dem,mann]
;  W = [dem,fernrohr].
```

as solutions, (regardless of `[den,fernrohr]` not being German). But Prolog finds only a single one and then loops. In a sense you can consider yourself happy, for you detected that problem early on. But imagine a situation where there are many answers before the loop. So you have the impression that everything is fine, but it is not.

To find those problems a bit faster, ask `pn(X), false` instead.  While this query will never be true, it will terminate in exactly the same way as `pn(X)` but it will not produce all those irritating solutions.

You can go even a step further by inserting **`false`** into your program, the resulting program is called a failure slice. With a pure, monotonic program as yours, the following holds:

> If a failure slice does not terminate (for a particular query) **then** the original program does not terminate for that query.

Failure slices are typically much shorter, so they are faster to read and understand. In the case of `np(X)`

```
?- np(X), false.

np(W) :-
   (  append(W1,W2,W), false,  pn(W1), ph(W2)
   ;  false, append(W1,W2,W), det(W1), n(W2)
   ).
```

So you no longer need to waste your time searching `pn/1`, `ph/1`, `det/1`, or `n/1` for loops. Above failure-slice alone is already producing non-termination. Thus: As long as this does not get fixed it is pointless to look at the remaining program.

A straight-forward fix would be to put `append/3` at the end. That works for `np/1`. But it does not work for recursive non-terminals with a list of fixed length.

Before Prolog was born, people did consider exactly such encodings. They were puzzled by this mismatch: Both grammars and predicate logic are declarative formalism.  But while many grammars can be parsed very efficiently, proving that a sentence is described by grammar seems to imply a gigantic search space. Where is this effective method to use logic here?

The answer was a particular encoding that permitted resolution to parse simple grammars as efficiently as handwritten parsers which thus gave birth to Prolog. To this date, this encoding is used in Prolog to implement Definite Clause Grammars. See @WouterBeeks's answer how this is done.

Comment: Thanks for explaining some of the theoretical foundations of DCG syntax in Prolog. I was not aware of the concept 'failure slice' before. For those interested in the topic: [this paper](http://mips.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/papers/PDF/1999-ppdp-corr.pdf) contains a thorough treatment of the matter.